# Tangent and Taylor polynomials

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

We know that this series $x+ \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+\ldots$ is convergent in $|x|\lt \pi/2$, furthermore it converges to $\tan(x)$.

I would like to know if we restrict to finite terms of this series can I have a good approximation of $\tan (x)$ even when $|x|\gt \pi/2$?

For example, this sum $x+ \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+\frac{17x^7}{315}$ is a good approximation to $\tan(x)$, when $|x|\gt\pi/2$? and if we go on and sum until the 30th order we will have a better approximation then the last one?

To sum up since the series is not convergent when $|x|\gt\pi/2$, I would like to know in this case if at least  the Taylor polynomial of this function can be useful when we take finite sums.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The radius of convergence of the series is $\pi/2$, so no, the sequence of partial sums diverges for $|x|>\pi/2$.

Comment: If $\;x>\frac\pi2\;$ but close to it, we have that $\;\tan x<0\;$ but that polynomial's value is positive. Why do you think  you' get a "good approximation"??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this series about $x=0$ but if $\pi/2<x_{0}<3\pi/2$ then the series around $x=\pi$ is convergent to  $\tan(x_0)$. In general, for $k\pi/2<x_{0}<k\pi/2+\pi$ the series $$(x-a)+\dfrac{(x-a)^3}{3}+\dfrac{2(x-a)^5}{15}+\cdots=\tan(x_0),$$
where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a=\frac{\pi(k+1)}{2}$.